# Triggering a hover or mouseover to get a defined CSS effect

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've tried to trigger a hover event on a previous row in a table so I could get it's effect defined in CSS but it's not working. Basically what I have is 2 rows joined that need this border effect for mouseovers whenever either row moused over. What is a solution in jQuery for this?

**jQuery**

```
$("tr").hover(function() {
  $(this).prev().trigger('mouseover');
});
```

**CSS**

```
tr:hover .row-right {
  border-right: 10px solid #CCC;
}
```

Comment: Could you please add your HTML code aswell

Comment: Triggering the `mouseover` event using JavaScript has no relation to the CSS `hover` property. See Yaron Uilel's answer for an alternative solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**jQuery**

```
 $("tr").mouseover(function() {
    $(this).prev().addClass('hover');
 });
 $("tr").mouseout(function() {
    $(this).prev().removeClass('hover');
 });
```

**CSS**

```
 tr.hover .row-right {
    border-right: 10px solid #CCC;
  }
```

jsFiddle link for this: http://jsfiddle.net/vsApc/

Comment: Can this be achieved by triggering some events on `$(this).prev()`? To avoid using hover class and use :hover instead.